# excel import to datatable with incorrect data types

Tags: c#

I have a excel document that I am importing to a DataTable. The price coloumn has a number with four decimal places eg 1234.2300. When doing the import I see the column type is int32 and I loose the leading zeros eg 1234.23. I would like to keep the zeros on import. How do I change the DataType of the DataTable ?

```
oConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + SavedFile + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");

                foreach (string sheet in sheets)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sheet))
                    {
                        string query = string.Format("Select * from [{0}$]", sheet);
                        OleDbDataAdapter cmd = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, oConn);

                        oDS.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                        cmd.Fill(oDS);
                        cmd = null;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the column type in Excel through right clicking the column header and selecting "format cell" and in the new menu select "text".
After you do that, it will return the numbers as Strings, and therefore the trailing zeroes will remain.

Comment: it still does not work if I change it to text or currency with 4 decimal places.